# wxpython :How I can get the word position in wxrichtextctrl when the window is resized?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, richtextbox

My program reads docx file using python-docs tools then display the text on wxrichtextctrl. I stored the screen position of each word ,when it is written on the richttextbox. The problem is when the window is re-sized by the user the words positions are changed how I can catch this change. Because I want to highlight and draw dashed underline for specific words.

Any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm able to get the character index of the word starting. If any one tell me how I can convert the character position to pixel on client area , it would be helpful.

Comment: If anyone has any idea about how to implement custom underline for text in multi-lines richtextbox would be helpful. I tried to draw dashed colored line under some words using wx.dc but the problem when the window re-sized all lines are disappeared.  Then I tried to bind the window to wx.EVT_PAINT event , but still I have problem to get the word position in pixel correctly to draw the line.